# Pointers on accessing an data object class C++

Tags: c++, oop

Just asking for pointers on how I could change the following programming practices (hope I am right to say things this way) so that I can improve my coding techniques and probably learn some new design method

I have inherited some old project code which declares data class object (pure data as members, with no member functions whatsoever) , something like below

```
class Data{
    public:
       int x;
       long y;
       ....
}
```

Then an instance of the class is declared ie `Data data`. Then every other class which uses this data object will use a member pointer Data* dataptr and the above object will have its memory location pass into the class at instantiation. (see below)

```
// in h file
class Otherclass{
    .....
   private:
      Data* dataptr;
}

// in cpp file
OtherClass::OtherClass(Data& data,........)
: ......,
  dataptr(&data),
{
   ......
}

// when need to create OtherClass object
OtherClass* x = new OtherClass(data,........);

// so on and so forth.. if we need to use it in other class we perform the same thing
// by having the class declaring Data* (pointer)
```

The above framework works.. However I have a feeling that the above is a bit C orientated and whether there are more modern way of doing things...  Just would like to ask for a few opinions question

1. Is there any unforseen problems in doing the above approach? Not quite sure if multiple class has pointers and accessing the memory space will have problems (though they mainly access the memory at different time/point)
2. What could I do instead of using above approach?

Thanks

EDIT
Addressing issues mentioned

1. Data object would exist throughout the lifecycle of program. The Data class behaves like structure and contains the current value it holds at each stage
2. OtherClass objects that holds the Data member pointer variable generally would also exist as long as the Data exist
3. Data object would be created and access and modified in stages by other different single OtherClass in each stage. eg Class A will access/modify Data in stage 1 and in stage 2 Class B will access/modify Data. This will go on in a loop until program is exited.
4. What I have bone to pick with this framework is it seems to be rather C in nature, I just wonder what I can do to replace or improve it in view of modern c++

Comment: Well in my opinion, the problem obviously is you have to be very cautious with this Data object lifetime. I think it might be better to use some `std::shared_ptr` with `std::weak_ptr` and check if object is expired inside each OtherClass member call.

Comment: [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ](https://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html)

Comment: This question isn't really answerable without knowing more about what you're actually trying to do. Are the `Data` instances _meant_ to be shared? Are they ever modified? Would it be correct to have one unique `Data` instance for each `OtherClass` instance? How is it allocated and who should deallocate it?

Answer (score 1):

You dont tell much about data: where does it comes from ? stack or heap allocation ? Who owns data and is responsible for its life cycle ?

When giving pointer to classes that stores it as a member you have to be very careful about life cycle.
For exemple, if data is allocated on the stake, since Otherclass is alocated with new, you are very likely to have an access violation with Otherclass accessing the address of data after it has been released.

If data is allocated with new, you should consider using smart pointer.
If data is allocated on the heap, your code will probably crash soon or later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're correct that multiple OtherClass instances with pointers to the same data instance will not create any data races since data isn't accessed simultaneously. You may have to watch out for the destruction of OtherClass objects. Just make sure to delete the data pointer in the destructor of OtherClass.

If you're worried about pointers, I would just use a principle called aggregation to include a member of type Data in OtherClass. You could still create one Data object and pass it to the OtherClass constructor by value.

Another big issue to watch out for using pointers is object lifetimes. Make sure that if you use pointers the Data object always outlives all OtherClass objects. If it doesn't, dangling pointers can be created. If you want the data to persist in OtherClass after Data is destructed, you should use aggregation.

Comment: "Just make sure to delete the data pointer in the destructor of OtherClass." This would cause all kinds of problems like multiple free/delete, as the instance is shared.

Comment: @paleonix I'm not sure how problems would arise. If multiple instances of OtherClass are pointing to Data, deleting an instance of OtherClass and its pointer to Data shouldn't affect any OtherClass instance's pointer to Data, or am I wrong?

Comment: Please read again what you have written.

Comment: @paleonix I have. I see that deleting Data would be problematic with pointers to it still existing, but with two pointers pointing to the same object, I don't see how deleting one pointer creates an issue with the other. I'm not suggesting deleting the data it points to, just the pointer itself.

Comment: Why would you need to delete it? It is a normal member whose lifetime is coupled to `OtherClass`. There is no need for a custom destructor.

Answer (score -1):

Using multiple classes with the same pointer is not the best approach. Especially that you are passing it in everytime you create an instance of the class. If you insist on using this approach, using the static keyword would be an improvement as you need the same pointer of Data to be shared across all instances of the class.
However, since you asked for a modern approach, you could use a Tuple. Since your class "Data" only has data members, you could create a Tuple with these data members (or a Pair if you only have two data members). A tuple (provided by c++ standard library) can have any fixed number of elements with different types. Example on how you can create a Tuple : `tuple<int, long, ...>data(x, y,...);`
You could read more about it here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Comment: I can't understand how using "Tuple" is related to original question. Moreover, replacing meaningful data structures with tuples just makes code worse.

Comment: @elo Well, using a tuple would prevent the need to use the Data class (and hence having to worry about dangling pointers). I do agree with you on tuples not always being the best approach, it would depend on the program. Based on the description provided, I thought that this is one of the cases where you could use a tuple without making the code "worse"

Comment: Assuming that the original data class has more meaningful names than `x` and `y` it certainly makes the code worse.